# How to return value in collection.find({})

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var shortLinks = [];

Link.find({}, function (err, links) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

    } else {

        links.map(link => {
            shortLinks.push(link.shortLink);
        });

    }
    console.log(shortLinks);//shortLinks has values, all okey
});

console.log(shortLinks); //shortLinks is empty
```

i need to use shortLinks after Link.find({}) but array is empty.
Need to return shortLinks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Before completion of your query Results your outside shortlinks gets printed as NodeJs  is asynchronous it does not wait for query to complete. So you are getting empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks.  The `function(err, links)` is called asynchronously, so `shortLinks` isn't populated until that function is called.  Your bottom `console.log` is being called first, due to how callbacks work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks

Answer (score 0):

need to use promise:

```
const shortLinks = [];

const getShortLinks = Link.find({}, function (err, links) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

    } else {

        links.map(link => {
            shortLinks.push(link.shortLink);
        });

    }
});

getShortLinks.then(function(links){
    console.log(shortLinks);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: You do not NEED to use `promise`.  It is a solution to the problem and an abstraction of the callback structure.  If you don't understand callbacks then you're going to have a bad time.